# Keys repeat too fast, regardless of option in settings

Tags: keyboard, keys

Since last reboot, the keys I've pressed have been repeating at a different speed than set in the setting. Moving the sliders or even turning "Repeat Keys" off doesn't make a difference. It's as if they are repeating at maximum speed, with no extra delay before the first repeated key. Both typing and the use of keyboard shortcuts are affected by this.

---

My assumption is that the settings are being overridden somewhere. I apologize for the lack of information, but I do not know how to approach this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently adding a new keyboard `Input Source` (in `System Settings` -> `Text Entry`) and then re-selecting the previous one has fixed the problem.

Edit: I also ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` prior to rebooting, so that could also be the reason why the problem disappeared.